# Error starting jboss server

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss5.x

I've just finished re-installing my OS, and as always install and test standard tools which I use, and now I get this error like never before when I tried to start Jboss 5 from eclipse, its quite big exeption :

```
3:53:10,693 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=AttachmentStore state=Described
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[java.net.URI] actual=[java.io.File]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.handleErrors(ReflectionUtils.java:395)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:153)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.newInstance(ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicConstructorJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicConstructorJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.createTarget(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:282)
    at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.dispatch(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:103)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstantiateAction.installActionInternal(InstantiateAction.java:66)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBeans(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:130)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.BasicKernelDeployer.deploy(BasicKernelDeployer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:91)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:161)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:450)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed:

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "AttachmentStore" is in error due to: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[java.net.URI] actual=[java.io.File]

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "ProfileServiceBootstrap" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "ProfileService" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=Kernel" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileServiceDeployer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AttachmentStore" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileService" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "ProfileServiceDeployer" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=KernelController" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileServicePersistenceDeployer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AttachmentStore" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")

    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.internalValidate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:278)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.validate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:174)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:142)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:450)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
23:53:11,600 INFO  [ServerImpl] Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
23:53:11,615 INFO  [ServerImpl] Shutdown complete
```

Did anyone had the similar problem before?I've never encountered it so far

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Looks like a bug that occurs with certain specific combinations of JRE and OS versions (see https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-6981). Basically, the JBoss config is relying on reflection to return constructors in a certain order, and in some cases this order is different, causing the exception.  Did you change your JRE version when you reinstalled, say from 1.6.0_17 to _18?

Anyway, the workaround is described in the JIRA issue, and also [here](http://community.jboss.org/thread/2390?tstart=0). You need to change the content of `conf/bootstrap/profile.xml`. Look for the definition of the `AttachmentStore`, and change the constructor line so that it starts like this (i.e. add the `class` XML attribute to the `parameter` tag):

```
<constructor><parameter class="java.io.File"><inject …
```

The original version doesn't have the `class="java.io.File"` attribute.

Pretty sloppy of the JBoss folks, but there you go.

Comment: I could not find AttachmentStore in profile.xml for current version of jboss5.0.1GA

Answer (score 0):

jboss-5.0.0.GA-JDK6/server/default/conf/bootstrap$ diff bindings.xml.old bindings.xml

In this file you have to change two things.
One:

Old

```
<bean name="StandardBindings" class="java.util.HashSet"
< elementClass="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
<constructor>
<parameter>
<set>
—New
<bean name="StandardBindings" class="java.util.HashSet">
 <constructor>
<parameter class="java.util.Collection">
 <set elementClass="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
```

Second: And then your http port number in the below bean definition

```
<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss.web:service=WebServer</property>
               <property name="port">7070</property>
```