# Error when starting JBoss 5.1.0.GA / AttachmentStore

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I'm getting this error when starting the JBoss server in Eclipse.

```
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed. 

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR
Deployment "AttachmentStore" is in error due to: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong arguments. new for taget java.land.reflect.Constructor expected=[java.net.URI] actual=[java.io.File]
```

I've googled the `AttachementStore` error and most suggested modifying the **profile.xml** (conf/bootstrap/profile.xml) file by adding a class to the constructor parameter node like this...

```
constructor parameter class="java.io.File"
```

Adding the `class="java.io.File"` seems to be the accepted solution everywhere since it's a known bug in JBoss but it didn't work for me.

I know I added the class correctly, I checked, rechecked and rechecked again the **profile.xml** file but JBoss is still throwing the same error when starting.  I'm completely baffled. Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489106/error-starting-jboss-server which also contains a well up-voted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Error mainly occurred due to upgrade java 6 to java 7 or 8. Previously I used jdk 6u10 and it is changed to jdk 7u45.

Run the projects using java release of jdk 6u10 or Sun JDK 1.6.0_13. JBOSS runs with these JDK version successfully.