# JBoss 5.1 GA: Deployment Error [IllegalArgumentException]

Tags: jboss5.x, ear

I deployed an .ear file and got this error. I'm new to JBoss, I don't know how to fix it.

```
18:36:15,903 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
18:36:15,904 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [The Oracle] 5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)
18:36:15,904 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
18:36:15,904 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA
18:36:15,904 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/
18:36:15,904 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/
18:36:15,905 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
18:36:15,905 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/
18:36:15,905 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/lib/
18:36:15,905 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/data
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/lib/
18:36:15,906 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/log
18:36:15,907 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/native
18:36:15,907 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp
18:36:15,907 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy
18:36:16,416 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
18:36:16,851 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.CombinedVFSCache]
18:36:16,854 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [CombinedVFSCache[real-cache: null]]
18:36:17,055 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: /Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp
18:36:17,056 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.
18:36:17,905 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.7.0_09,Oracle Corporation
18:36:17,905 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
18:36:17,905 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.5-b02,Oracle Corporation
18:36:17,906 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Mac OS X 10.7.5,x86_64
18:36:17,907 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/ronyjohn007/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/endorsed 
18:36:17,934 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
18:36:19,183 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=AttachmentStore state=Described
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[java.net.URI] actual=[java.io.File]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.handleErrors(ReflectionUtils.java:395)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:153)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.newInstance(ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicConstructorJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicConstructorJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.createTarget(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:282)
    at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.dispatch(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:103)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstantiateAction.installActionInternal(InstantiateAction.java:66)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBeans(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:130)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.BasicKernelDeployer.deploy(BasicKernelDeployer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:91)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:161)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:450)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed:

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "AttachmentStore" is in error due to: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[java.net.URI] actual=[java.io.File]

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "ProfileService" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "ProfileServiceDeployer" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=KernelController" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileServiceDeployer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AttachmentStore" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileServiceBootstrap" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "ProfileService" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=Kernel" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileServicePersistenceDeployer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AttachmentStore" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")

    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.internalValidate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:278)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.validate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:174)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:142)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:450)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
18:36:19,633 INFO  [ServerImpl] Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
18:36:19,638 INFO  [ServerImpl] Shutdown complete
Shutdown complete
Halting VM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error starting jboss server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489106/error-starting-jboss-server)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can try this one.

Open the file profile.xml in jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\bootstrap

find the  "The attachment store" block :

add "class="java.io.File" in 《parameter》.

Or you can try this link:
[Error when starting JBoss 5.1.0.GA / AttachmentStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316857/error-when-starting-jboss-5-1-0-ga-attachmentstore?lq=1)

PATH to the Direct solution: [Error starting jboss server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489106/error-starting-jboss-server)

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me !! thank you ! But can you please explain what we are doing here?

Answer (score 13):

Open the file profile.xml

jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\bootstrap\profile.xml and then

> Replace-->

```
<bean name="AttachmentStore" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractAttachmentStore">  
     <constructor><parameter><inject bean="BootstrapProfileFactory" property="attachmentStoreRoot" /></parameter></constructor>
```

> With -->

```
<bean name="AttachmentStore" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractAttachmentStore">  
 <constructor>><parameter class="java.io.File"><inject bean="BootstrapProfileFactory" property="attachmentStoreRoot" /></parameter></constructor>
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed the java_home from 1.7 to 1.6 and that solved the issue for me (in bin\run.conf or bin\run.conf.bat) without changing conf/bootstrap/profile.xml

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved similarly to gribo. My path variables were correctly pointing to JDK6 (I'm running JBoss5.1 with JDK6). But in eclipse, my JBoss runtime JRE was pointing to JRE8. The problem went away once I pointed it to JRE6.

I also did not have to change conf/bootstrap/profile.xml. I tried that first and it didn't fix my problem.