# JBoss startup errors

Tags: startup, jboss5.x

I am trying to set up jboss on my machine and getting errors. There are 2 errors. One when i try to run jboss standalone, second when i try to run it from eclipse.

For the moment, I haven't deployed any application.

The first error is realted to some port, which i am not sure in which file i should edit

```
13:26:01,913 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss:service=invoker,type=pooled state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
java.lang.Exception: Port 4445 is already in use
        at org.jboss.invocation.pooled.server.PooledInvoker.startService(PooledInvoker.java:230)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:322)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:189)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doInstall(ServiceController.java:670)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.register(ServiceController.java:373)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerRegistrationLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerRegistrationLifecycleCallback.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor232.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
        at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
        at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1568)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1533)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.jmx.ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.install(ServiceControllerStartStopLifecycleCallback.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
        at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
        at org.jboss.beans.info.plugins.AbstractBeanInfo.invoke(AbstractBeanInfo.java:300)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelControllerContext.invoke(AbstractKernelControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.install(AbstractLifecycleCallbackItem.java:87)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1568)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.handleInstallLifecycleCallbacks(AbstractController.java:1533)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:943)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
        at org.jboss.net.sockets.DefaultSocketFactory.createServerSocket(DefaultSocketFactory.java:124)
        at org.jboss.invocation.pooled.server.PooledInvoker.startService(PooledInvoker.java:224)
```

I could track down the file **bindings-jboss-beans.xml** but it exist in multiple locations. What file should i be editing?

*** I FIXED PROBLEM 1, i edited `%JBOSS_HOME%\server\default\conf\bindingservice.beans\META-INF\bindings-jboss-beans.xml`

The **second error** is when i try to run it with in eclipse.

```
13:26:54,787 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=AttachmentStore state=Described
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[java.net.URI] actual=[java.io.File]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.handleErrors(ReflectionUtils.java:395)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:153)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.newInstance(ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.java:106)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicConstructorJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicConstructorJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.createTarget(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:282)
    at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.dispatch(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:103)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstantiateAction.installActionInternal(InstantiateAction.java:66)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBeans(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:130)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.BasicKernelDeployer.deploy(BasicKernelDeployer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:91)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:161)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:450)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed:

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "AttachmentStore" is in error due to: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[java.net.URI] actual=[java.io.File]

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "ProfileServiceBootstrap" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=Kernel" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
    Dependency "ProfileService" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
  Deployment "ProfileServicePersistenceDeployer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AttachmentStore" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileService" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "ProfileServiceDeployer" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=KernelController" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "ProfileServiceDeployer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AttachmentStore" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "**ERROR**")
```

Comment: hi ..i cannot find folder "JBOSS_HOME%\server\default\conf\bindingservice.beans\META-INF\bindings-jboss-beans.xml" where else can I edit the port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second error : 
It is a specific bug with some combinations or JRE and OS versions

You can find how to solve it here: 
 
[Solve Second Error SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489106/error-starting-jboss-server)

 Try it and tell me if it resolves your problem.