# Not able to start JBoss 5.1 GA on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, jboss5.x

I have no clue about what am I wrong in here.

[image]

```
C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin>run.bat
Calling C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\run.conf.bat
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun
.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dorg
.jboss.resolver.warning=true -server

  CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\run.jar

===============================================================================

log4j:ERROR Failed to create directory structure: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5
.1.0.GA\server\default\log
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\defa
ult\log\boot.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:2
56)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.j
ava:132)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.j
ava:96)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigura
tor.java:654)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigura
tor.java:612)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyC
onfigurator.java:509)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurato
r.java:415)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurato
r.java:441)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionCon
verter.java:470)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
        at org.jboss.logging.log4j.Log4jLoggerPlugin.init(Log4jLoggerPlugin.java
:70)
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getDelegatePlugin(Logger.java:603)
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:119)
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:567)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.doInit(AbstractServerImpl.java
:204)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.init(AbstractServerImpl.java:1
73)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.init(AbstractServerImpl.java:1
43)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:218)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
11:42:08,937 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
11:42:08,938 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [The Oracle] 5.1.0.GA (build:
SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)
11:42:08,939 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
11:42:08,939 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA
11:42:08,940 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBOSS/jboss-5
.1.0.GA/
11:42:08,940 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBOSS/jbos
s-5.1.0.GA/lib/
11:42:08,942 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
11:42:08,942 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBOSS/
jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/
11:42:08,943 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBO
SS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/lib/
11:42:08,944 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default
11:42:08,944 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.
1.0.GA\server
11:42:08,945 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBOSS/
jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/
11:42:08,946 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBOS
S/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/
11:42:08,946 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.
1.0.GA\server\default
11:42:08,947 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBOSS/
jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/
11:42:08,947 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.
1.0.GA\server\default\data
11:42:08,948 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JBO
SS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/lib/
11:42:08,949 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1
.0.GA\server\default\log
11:42:08,949 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-
5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\native
11:42:08,950 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.
1.0.GA\server\default\tmp
11:42:08,951 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\j
boss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\deploy
11:42:09,548 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/C:/P
rogram%20Files/JBOSS/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
11:42:10,125 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.pl
ugins.cache.CombinedVFSCache]
11:42:10,129 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [CombinedVFSCache[real-cache
: null]]
11:42:10,409 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.
1.0.GA\server\default\tmp
11:42:10,411 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.

11:42:10,667 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=A
spectManager state=Configured
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Failed to create tmpClassesDir: C:\Program Files\
JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\aopdynclasses
        at org.jboss.aop.asintegration.core.AspectManagerServiceDelegate.create(
AspectManagerServiceDelegate.java:237)
        at org.jboss.aop.deployers.AbstractAspectManager.create(AbstractAspectMa
nager.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(Reflec
tionUtils.java:59)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(
ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
        at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethod
JoinPoint.java:66)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$Joi
npointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(Executio
nWrapper.java:47)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dis
patchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dis
patchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInte
rnal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction
(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction
(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.sim
pleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.ins
tall(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install
(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:774)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:540)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean
(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean
s(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(Abs
tractKernelDeployer.java:130)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.BasicKernelDeployer.deploy(BasicK
ernelDeployer.java:76)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBa
sicXMLDeployer.java:91)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBa
sicXMLDeployer.java:161)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java
:138)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:
450)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
11:42:11,350 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_34,Sun Microsystems Inc.
11:42:11,350 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (b
uild 1.6.0_34-b04)
11:42:11,351 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.9-
b04,Sun Microsystems Inc.
11:42:11,352 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
11:42:11,353 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128M -X
mx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dg
c.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.endorsed.di
rs=C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA\lib\endorsed
11:42:11,384 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed:

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "AspectManager" is in error due to: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
Failed to create tmpClassesDir: C:\Program Files\JBOSS\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\def
ault\tmp\aopdynclasses

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "JMXStartStopAdvice$AspectBinding" is missing the following depende
ncies:
    Dependency "AspectManager" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually
in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "BeansDeploymentAopMetaDataDeployer" is missing the following depen
dencies:
    Dependency "AspectManager" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually
in state "**ERROR**")
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=Kernel" (should be in state "Installed", bu
t is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "AOPDeploymentAopMetaDataDeployer" is missing the following depende
ncies:
    Dependency "AspectManager" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually
in state "**ERROR**")
    Dependency "jboss.kernel:service=Kernel" (should be in state "Installed", bu
t is actually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "AOPClassLoaderDeployer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AspectManager" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually
in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "JMXRegistrationAdvice$AspectBinding" is missing the following depe
ndencies:
    Dependency "AspectManager" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually
in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "AspectManagerJMXRegistrar" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "AspectManager" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually
in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "JMXCreateDestroyAdvice$AspectBinding" is missing the following dep
endencies:
    Dependency "AspectManager" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually
in state "**ERROR**")

        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.internalVa
lidate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:278)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.validate(A
bstractKernelDeployer.java:174)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java
:142)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:
450)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
11:42:13,576 INFO  [ServerImpl] Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
11:42:13,582 INFO  [ServerImpl] Shutdown complete
Shutdown complete
Halting VM
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug that occurs with certain specific combinations of JRE and OS versions (see https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-6981). Basically, the JBoss config is relying on reflection to return constructors in a certain order, and in some cases this order is different, causing the exception. Did you change your JRE version when you reinstalled, say from 1.6.0_17 to _18?

Anyway, the workaround is described in the JIRA issue, and also here. You need to change the content of conf/bootstrap/profile.xml. Look for the definition of the AttachmentStore, and change the constructor line so that it starts:

The original version doesn't have the class="java.io.File" attribute.

Pretty sloppy of the JBoss folks, but there you go.
 Hope it helps.

(copied from [Error starting jboss server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489106/error-starting-jboss-server))