# JBoss starting with java.io.FileInputStream Error when initializing AbstractKernelController

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, profile, bootstrapping

We have a troublesome JBoss server that recently displayed a new error and refuses to load our web application. No changes have been made to any configuration files - the error just appeared suddenly.

Read all of the JBoss startup,classloader, and bootstrap issues and followed the remedy at: [Error starting jboss server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489106/error-starting-jboss-server?rq=1) but the solutions did not work for us. I apologize for my lack of knowledge and if this is an easy fix. We appreciate the assistance.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (Thread-2) Error installing to create: name=b81232b8 aliases=[ProfileKey@421c8a02[domain=default, server=default, name=farm]) 
  state=Configured mode=Manual requiredState=Installed: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: java.io.FileInputStream@4d4352b2
  at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.clustered.local.AbstractContentMetadataPersister.load(AbstractContentMetadataPersister.java:76)
  at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.clustered.local.AbstractLocalContentManager.<init>(AbstractLocalContentManager.java:139)
  at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.clustered.local.file.FilesystemLocalContentManager.<init>(FilesystemLocalContentManager.java:68)
  at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.clustered.local.file.FilesystemLocalContentManagerFactory.getLocalContentManager(FilesystemLocalContentManagerFactory.java:98)
  at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.clustered.ClusteredDeploymentRepository.create(ClusteredDeploymentRepository.java:201)
  at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.clustered.ClusteredDeploymentRepository.load(ClusteredDeploymentRepository.java:242)
  at org.jboss.profileservice.repository.legacy.DelegateProfile.create(DelegateProfile.java:138)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccesorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  ...
```

Comment: Traced the exception in the AbstractContentMetadataPersister class at: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-system/5.1.0.CR1/org/jboss/system/server/profileservice/repository/clustered/local/AbstractContentMetadataPersister.java but it seems like it just catches a generic Exception. I wonder if JBoss has issues reading a configuration file or a particular property. Do not see the AttachmentStore definition in our profile.xml file.

Comment: Going further down the stack trace we see that there is a org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Premature end of file. @ *unknown*[-1,-1] error. The instructions listed on https://community.jboss.org/thread/162453?_sscc=t do not work. The closest error I found is at: https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/528413 but does not have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was laughably simple. We cleared the auto-generated jboss/data directory and it fixed everything. Some binding files must have been corrupted and a clean restart had things working again.