# WebService error while deploying - Wrong arguments

Tags: java, jboss, esb, jboss5.x, jboss-esb

Deploying my new service on JBOSS SOA-P 5 stops with error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Instantiated: name=jboss.esb.vfszip:/D:/servers/jboss-soa-p-5/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/MyFooService.esb/ state=Described
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor 
expected=[org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbMetaData, java.lang.String, org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.VFSDeploymentUnit, java.io.File] 
  actual=[org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbMetaData, java.lang.String, org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSDeploymentUnit, java.io.File]
```

I already read this topic: [Error starting jboss server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489106/error-starting-jboss-server). However it didnt help me too much.

Full stacktrace:

```
2015-07-06 11:37:33,624 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (HDScanner) Error installing to Instantiated: name=jboss.esb.vfszip:/D:/servers/jboss-soa-p-5/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/WartaSprawdzHistoriePosiadaniaKlienta.esb/ state=Described
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbMetaData, java.lang.String, org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.VFSDeploymentUnit, java.io.File] actual=[org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbMetaData, java.lang.String, org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSDeploymentUnit, java.io.File]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.handleErrors(ReflectionUtils.java:395)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:153)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.newInstance(ReflectConstructorInfoImpl.java:106)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicConstructorJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicConstructorJoinPoint.java:80)
at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.createTarget(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:296)
at org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.integration.AOPConstructorJoinpoint.dispatch(AOPConstructorJoinpoint.java:115)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:243)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:111)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstantiateAction.installActionInternal(InstantiateAction.java:66)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:125)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:52)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
at      org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2015-07-06 11:37:33,630 WARN  [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner] (HDScanner) Failed to process changes
org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
Deployment "jboss.esb.vfszip:/D:/servers/jboss-soa-p-5/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/WartaSprawdzHistoriePosiadaniaKlienta.esb/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong arguments. new for target java.lang.reflect.Constructor expected=[org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbMetaData, java.lang.String, org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.structure.VFSDeploymentUnit, java.io.File] actual=[org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.deployers.mc.EsbMetaData, java.lang.String, org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSDeploymentUnit, java.io.File]

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1008)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:954)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:870)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:416)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was using wrong version of jbossesb-rosetta which was provided already on my server. When i add `provided` to dependecy, errors disapeared.